# How to call VB6 COM from C++/CLI

Tags: .net, interop, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I have situation where i have to call the VB6 COM from the C++/CLI. This thing can be achieved using the C# by adding the reference of VB6 dll in the Project because the Interop dll is automatically gets generated there.

But, my situation is bit different because i am using c++/CLI and need a way to call VB6 COM from C++/CLI code.

Secondly, is it possible to generate the .tlh of the VB6 COM.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the reference of the VB6 Dll in your c++/CLI project by going to 
Project->Properties->Common Properties->Framework and References->Add New Reference.

Now select your VB6.dll and it will generate the required Interop and then you are good to call the VB6 from c++/CLI.